Handling (loading) Excel Files with Multiple Sheets in KNIME
Attached is the KNIME workflow to load mutiple Excel files with mutiple sheets into an excel file. These excel sheets contains fields as columns so needs some manupulation. However, I have noted when I run this workflow, it duplicates the first sheet of each workbook.


The solution is to select file and sheet tab on excel reader, then select the radial button "By Name".


In your Excel Reader >> "Flow Variables" Menu click the plus sign on the Settings grouping. Set the sheet_name setting to whatever variable you have the sheet name loaded as.
Then on the "File and Sheet" Menu, set your "Select Sheet" to the "By name" bubble. This should adjust the sheet thats read in to whatever is loaded in the loop.
